# Formatting decimal xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, decimalformat

I am new to c# and I couldn't find a way to format my numbers. I want to show only 2 digits after decimal.

```
namespace Dolar
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
            doc1.Load("http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml");
            XmlElement root = doc1.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("Currency");

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                var attributeKod = node.Attributes["Kod"].Value;
                if (attributeKod.Equals("USD"))
                {
                    var a = node.SelectNodes("BanknoteSelling")[0].InnerText;
                    var b = node.SelectNodes("BanknoteBuying")[0].InnerText;
                    float c = float.Parse(a);
                    float d = float.Parse(b);                 
                    label2.Text = a;
                    label3.Text = b;


                }

                var attributeKod1 = node.Attributes["Kod"].Value;
                if(attributeKod1.Equals("EUR"))
                {
                    var a = node.SelectNodes("BanknoteSelling")[0].InnerText;
                    var b = node.SelectNodes("BanknoteBuying")[0].InnerText;
                    float c = float.Parse(a);
                    float d = float.Parse(b);
                    label4.Text = a;
                    label5.Text = b;
                }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

outputs are;

```
4.5173 //4.51
4.4992 //4.49
5.3131 //5.31
5.2919 //5.29
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you aren't assigning your parsed `float` variables (c and d) to the textboxes. You can use the format specifier "0.00", like so:

```
var c = float.Parse(a);
var d = float.Parse(b);
label4.Text = c.ToString("0.00");
label5.Text = d.ToString("0.00");
```

You've also mixed implicit typed `var` variables and explicitly typed variables (e.g. `float c`). I would suggest sticking to `var`

Answer (score 3):

you can format them like this :

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 4.5173);    output will be  // "4.51"
```

or :
by using Math class :

```
float value = 4.5173;
value = System.Math.Round(value,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the built in formats.

In your case it's `i.ToString("F2")` or even `i.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` .

The `2` signifies 2 decimal places, and the `F` signifies the Fixed-Point Format.

See source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#FFormatString

You should test this, however, as I'm not sure this is correct for Xamarin. It's for .Net.